# Re-install custom feature in Idnetity Server 4.1.0 not working

Tags: installation, wso2-identity-server

I am working on a custom feature and did install it the Identity Server. After some fixes I wanted to re-install the feature, so what I did was 1) uninstall the feature, 2) restart server (graceful) 3) install the feature. The repository points to my local p2-repos which is generated in the build of maven.
The Identity Server does NOT accept the new feature. It is NOT showing any error in the console, neither in the web-admin. But when I test the feature I can see in the console and my debug outputs that the install-manager did not renew the jars.

My workaround now is to delete the whole server and do the install-process each time I want to try my code.

Can anyone confirm this bug?

Comment: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14394 - I saw this bug on the wso2-carbon jira-list. The answer is that 'this is how Equinox P2 works'. Still I don't know how to interchange a feature which is already installed. This is done by the version number?

Answer (score 0):

If your feature is correctly installed,  you can see your new jars in /repository/components/plugins directory.  If not, Please copy all OSGI (jar files) in your feature in to /repository/components/dropins directory and  restart the server. Also. you can use OSGI console to check whether bundles are properly activated. 
Just start server with  --DosgiConsole  option. then you would promote a OSGI console. you can check whether new bundles are active or not.

Comment: Asela, thank you for your response. Just to clear it up: **case 1**) I have already installed feature X-1.0.0, so when I want to exchange the files I replace them en /repository/components/plugins. **case 2**) I want to replace the same feature but with another (mvn-)Release version number, so I have to uninstall the previouse version and install the new versoin **case 3**) I am developing a new feature, so I can use the dropins folder for testing.